# Overlaying the whole ROS folder

Tags: ros, catkin, overlay, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question is about overlaying the whole ROS folder in `/opt/`. Since the packages source code in `/opt/ros` is not available, and changing parameters of the config files in `/opt/ros` is not recommended, is it possible to overlay the whole ros folder in `/opt/` to the user's workspace to modify the codes and change the parameters without interfering with the actual ros packages in `/opt/ros`

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190255/overlaying-the-whole-ros-folder/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure whether you'd need to overlay all the ROS packages, so I'm assuming this is not the case.

Your (catkin, I'm assuming) workspace is already an overlay of the system-wide installation and hence whatever ROS packages you have there will take precedence over the system-wide installation (provided your shell is properly configured and your workspace is sourced).

This way, you can place the source of the packages you want to overlay in your workspace, make the desired changes, build and use them without a problem.

However, depending on what sort of parameters you are talking about, they might be configurable via the parameter server and you won't even need to overlay the packages at all. You can set parameters manually from the terminal using [rosparam](http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam), [remap topics](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments), or configure them in a launch file using [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch).

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1